# How would core size affect plate tectonics?

Tags: geology, tectonics

If, for example, the Earth had a larger core (perhaps even Mercury-ratio) what effects would this have? Would continental drift speed up, slow down, or not even happen at all?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: A similar question was answered on worldbuilding - https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/177658/what-if-earths-core-was-bigger-than-now